# Maximal Nonoverlapping Subsets?

Tags: algorithm

Given 100 (possibly intersecting) subsets of 100 distinct items, what is the maximal number of subsets that can be selected such that they do not overlap.

One way to do this would be:

```
for i in 100 downto 0
   foreach choice C of (100 choose i) subsets:
      if (no two elements of C overlap)
          return i;
```

But obviously this is too slow.  Is there a polynomial time solution?

Comment: Since the size of the input is fixed, you already have an O(1) solution :p

Comment: maximal number is obviously 101: 1-element subsets and an empty one.

Comment: Don't know if it helps, but if interpret each set as a node and two nodes as connected when they don't overlap, you are looking for the maximum cluster of dense subgraphs (dense meaning: every node is connected to every other node, don't know the correct term).

Comment: @larsmans: Obviously I mean varying the 100 parameter as N to infinity.

Comment: @Vlad: Obviously the specific 100 subsets are an input parameter.

Comment: @Andrew: "varying the 100 parameter as N" -- which of the 100s? both simultaneously?

Comment: @Vlad: Sure, both are varied.

Answer (score 2):

This is [Set packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing), a classical NP-complete problem. There is no polynomial time solution.

Comment: Hmmm, you're right of course.  I must have missed some constraint on the input parameters.  Thanks.

Comment: The OPs's problem is not strictly set packing, as the set packing just asks whether there is a packing, and not what is the maximal one. Maybe you see how to reduce the original problem to set packing?

Comment: @Vlad: this is optimization version of set packing. To reduce it to the decision version of set packing, just use binary (or linear) search for number of subsets and check if packing is possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972092/maximal-subset-of-graph-verticies-that-are-not-connected

Comment: @Evgeny: don't we need it other way round? Perhaps we need to demonstrate that solving OP's problem in polynomial time would give the set packing solution in polynomial time as well.

Comment: @Vlad: If you can solve optimization problem in polynomial time, and you can reduce it to decision problem in polynomial time, than you would have a polynomial solution to decision problem.  So optimization problem is at least as hard as decision problem.