# Size of maximal subset of directed graph verticies that are not connected?

Tags: algorithm

Given a directed graph, how can I find the size of a maximal subset of verticies such that no two of them are connected by a directed path?

Does this problem (or the algorithm that solves it) have a common name?

(**Hint:** "According to Dilworth's theorem, this problem is actually equivalent to the minimum number of chains cover on a DAG after calculate the transitive closure. Thus, this problem can be reduce to maximum match on bipartite graph.")

Comment: If you first construct the transitive closure, then the subset you seek will be a maximum independent set in that graph.  (Evgeny Kluev was very close...)

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Yes but the resulting graph is bipartite, so there is a P time solution.

Comment: How do you know it's bipartite?

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Sorry actually it's not that simple, but see hint.

Comment: Interesting question. But, I think, you've completely answered it in the "hint". Wikipedia page, describing Dilworth's theorem, gives simple and efficient algorithm in section ["Proof via König's theorem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem#Proof_via_K.C3.B6nig.27s_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the name, I guess it's a sub problem of the [Disjoint-set data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)

Using Union Find, you can determine all the connected graph.

Initially, each node is on its group. Check every node and add all its direct children to the node's group root. This is basic Union Find.

The largest subset is then composed by one vertice from each group.

In worst case, which when every node is connected to all other nodes, this should take O(n²) as every node is checked n time.